# Host ASP.Net MVC Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localhost, web-deployment

I've created a site using ASP.Net MVC that is meant to be stored on a local machine at my place of work. The intention is to have the site stored on this machine, but then accessible by all the other machines within this building.

I've followed [Microsoft's tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) as well as [Code Project's tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1168712/How-to-Quickly-Configure-your-MVC-Website-in-IIS), but I am not having very much luck.  The binding is just the localhost, port 80, with * for the IP address. The URL is localhost/GrantTracker.

I've opened the ports within the firewall, checked the permissions on the directory (which is just within wwwroot), tried having the site take the place of the default IIS site (as Microsoft tutorial has you do) and tried having the site stand on its own with its own port (per Code Projects tutorial).

On the host machine I am receiving the standard "This site can't be reached, localhost refused to connect" which feels like either a port or permissions problem. I must be missing a step, but I can't seem to find what it would be. I am new to hosting sites through IIS so forgive me if I am just missing something basic.

I find it a bit strange too because my project uses Windows Authentication and when the site is first visited it performs that initial check with the user, authenticates, but then throws me the error.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding a simple html page to a website in IIS and make sure that works first. 
Which version of Windows are you running, which version of IIS? Are any websites working on that server?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am running Windows 10 and the IIS version is 10.0.17134.1.  The original IIS default page was working, but I can't seem to get my new site to show up.  I suppose I could make a quick HTML site and see if I can see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start simple, 
create a simple html page, create an IIS application for it, on port 80.
Check and make sure you can see that page from another computer using the internal IP address of the the host machine so something like:

`http:\\192.168.0.3\hostapp\test.html` .

You can see the proper URL by running it from IIS, this will give you the entire URL you need, with localhost then just replace localhost with the IP address of the host machine to see it on other machines.

Do this in the original IIS folder so you don't encounter any folder permission issues. If you choose another folder you'll have to give access to the Network Service user ( i think, can't remember now, but there is a specific user that needs access to the folder where the website is deployed )

if you can see the page then deploy a proper website and do the same thing. Make sure the app pool is created correctly and it's up and running, then access it again on other computers and it should work.

Port 80 should be open by default so that should not be an issue.

Comment: I like it.  Simple, logical, and it makes sense.  I'll see what I can do.  Thank you, sir!